# Azure "My Images" can't be deployed in Virtual Network

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

When deploying a new Virtual Machine in Microsoft Azure, if I select a image from "my images" in the gallery, I can't select the Virtual Network in which I would like to see it deployed.

Is it a Azure restriction or a web-portal-interface limitation (and then is it possible to perform such deployment via PowerShell)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image will have to be available in the right region (its a pain, i know). So, if your Vnet is in East US, your image will have to reside in a storage account in that region.

Comment: If my Virtual Network is on Est US 2, I can't do it so? 
(As when registering the VM image, Est US 2 isn't provided as an option... and that my previous image was already on Est US)

Comment: Not sure I understand. Upload an image to a storage account in East US 2 and register it as a VM image?

Comment: East US 2 isn't available as an option: http://i.imgur.com/ACGCyW2.png I will try to redeploy a new Virtual Network in East US then.

Comment: Ok with East US I can now deploy a VM. Thanks!